# Authorize access to Google Cloud Translate from Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a Firebase Cloud Function that calls Google Cloud Translate. I'm getting this error:

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud IAM permission 'cloudtranslate.generalModels.predict' denied.
```

It appears that my credentials aren't being passed from the Firebase Cloud Function to Google Cloud Translate. I set up a [user-managed service account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#adding_a_user-managed_service_account_at_deployment), First I tried this to deploy from the CLI:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:ENtranslateES --service-account google-cloud-translate@my-awesome-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

That threw this error:

```
error: unknown option '--service-account'
```

Then I tried this:

```
gcloud functions deploy ENtranslateES --service-account google-cloud-translate@my-awesome-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

That worked. I got a lengthy response on the CLI without errors and I see in my Google Cloud Console that the Cloud Function `ENtranslateES` was last deployed at the time that I executed that command.

Triggering the Firebase Cloud Function continues to return the `PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud IAM permission` error.

Here's my code:

```js
exports.ENtranslateES = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/English/Translation_Request').onUpdate((change) => { 
    const { TranslationServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/translate').v3;
    const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient();
    const projectId = 'my-awesome-app';
    const location = 'global';
    const text = 'Hello, world!';

    async function translateText() {
        const request = {
            parent: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}`,
            contents: [text],
            mimeType: 'text/plain', // mime types: text/plain, text/html
            sourceLanguageCode: 'en',
            targetLanguageCode: 'es',
        };

        const [response] = await translationClient.translateText(request);

        for (const translation of response.translations) {
            console.log(`Translation: ${translation.translatedText}`);
        }
    }

    return translateText()

});
```

I also set up a POST query from Postman to Google Cloud Translate. I entered Authorization properties for `Client ID`, `Client Secret`, `Auth URL`, `Access Token URL`, etc. The Postman query worked. Should I put my `Client ID`, `Client Secret`, etc. in my Firebase Cloud Function code? From what I've read it appears that this is unnecessary if I deploy the function with a service account.

Comment: Google's libraries use Application Default Credentials to acquire credentials automatically. When you run e.g. a Cloud Function function as an e.g. user-managed Service Account, the function uses the Service Account as its identity and if it uses Google libraries, these will transparently auth as that identity too.

Comment: However (!?) you will need to bind your user-managed Service Account to a role that includes `cloudtranslate.generalModels.predict`. Did you do that?

Comment: See Translate's [roles:permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-translation-roles). Maybe `roles/cloudtranslate.user`?

Comment: Can you try to update the client creation with that line ` const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient({projectID});`? By changing the projectID with YOUR project ID (where the API is activated)

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere, inserting my projectID (in 'quotes', because it's a string) in `TranslationServiceClient('my-awesome-app')` didn't help. :-(  Maybe projectID is the wrong credential to insert. My project has about 15 functions. I'll try inserting the client_email credential.

Comment: Can you try using service-[project-number]@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com as this is used to operate Cloud Functions for Firebase based on this documentation on [Firebase service account](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts)?

Comment: @Robert G, that produced a different error message, which told me to run another CLI command, which resulted in another error message. The first error message was "Missing necessary permission iam.serviceAccounts.actAs for cloud-functions-mixer on the service account service-my-sister's-phone-number@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com."

Comment: I checked whether `gcloud deploy` and `firebase deploy` were creating different cloud functions. They're not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working! Here's what I learned.

I connected a Firebase Cloud Function to Google Cloud Translate using an IAM service account. These instructions should also work for Google Cloud Functions and for other Google Cloud Services.

The overview of [Securing Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing?hl=en) says cloud function security can be either *identity-based* or *network-based*. In the identity based category, you can use either a *user account* (username and password) or a *service account*. Service accounts appear to be the preferred method so in this answer I will only discuss service accounts.

### IAMs and Service Accounts

The Google Cloud Console can be overwhelming at first. You start with a user account, which might be your gmail address. Then you make an organization, and in your organization you make a project.

Then look for `IAM & Admin`. `IAM` stands for *Identity Access Management*. Service accounts look like email addresses. This provides an *identity* to your Cloud Functions in the Googleverse. In other words, making a service account for your Cloud Functions enables it to interact with other stuff in the Google Cloud. The document [Function Identity](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity?hl=en) discusses this aspect of service accounts.

Service accounts have *principals* and *roles*. One of your service accounts should be your email address with your name and the role *Owner*. The document [Using IAM to Authorize Acces](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam?hl=en)s shows how to grant principals and roles to a service account.

Think of the other service accounts as your minions, who do your bidding. Some were automatically created when you signed up for Google Cloud Services.

You create new service accounts when you want to do stuff. For example, I wrote a Firebase Cloud Function that translates English into Spanish. I want this function to call Google Cloud Translate. A service account is designed to do one thing. Service accounts are email addresses that end in `iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

Because a service account does something you assign a role to a service account. In this case, my service account calls Google Cloud Translate so I assign it the role `Cloud Translation API User`.

Because a service account does *only one thing* you assign a *limited role* to a service account. My translation service account doesn't get to do stuff in the Google Cloud Dataplex, for example. It also doesn't get to be a `Cloud Translation API Editor` or `Admin`. It's just a `Cloud Translation API User` minion.

### Make a Service Account

In your Google Cloud Console, under `IAM & Admin` look for `Service Accounts` in the left sidebar. In the top bar look for `+ CREATE SERVICE ACCOUNT`.

You can name your service account anything you want. I suggest giving it the name of your Firebase Cloud Function. This makes it clear what the service account is for. To make extra clear write in the `Service account description` something like `This service account hooks up the Firebase Cloud Function SuperTranslator to Google Cloud Translate.` At some point in the future you'll have too many service accounts and you'll want to delete some.

Click `DONE`.

### Assign a Role to a Service Account

Now click `IAM` under `IAM & Admin` in the left sidebar. Your service account should be there, because services accounts are a special type of IAM.

On the right side click the pencil associated with your service account. Under `Assign roles` scroll through the hundreds of options to find the Google Cloud Product or Service that you want your service account to use. After selecting the product or service select a role.

As I noted earlier, assign the lowest role that enables your function to work. In the case of my translation function, there are four choices: `Admin`, `Editor`, `User`, and `Reader`. The lowly `Reader` minions are only allowed to read policies and org descriptions. `User` minions get to access the Google Cloud service. That's what I want my service account to do. `Editor` gets to edit policies and org descriptions and `Admin` has full access to policies and org descriptions. I don't want this service account to do that stuff.

Back on your `IAM` page, you'll notice on the right that each IAM has a count of *excess permissions* (in blue). This might be an `Admin` role that is only asked to perform `User` level stuff. Clicking the blue triangle sometimes recommends that you do something to reduce excess permissions. To rephrase what I said earlier, the purpose of IAMs is to give each minion just enough authority to do its job, and no more.

### Download your Service Account JSON File

Now you'll download your credentials to your computer. In your Google Cloud Console, go to `IAM and admin`, then `Service accounts`. Click on the service account you want.

Select the `KEYS` tab. Click the `ADD KEYS` button and select `Create new key`. Select the `JSON` radio button. A modal window will open asking you where to download the key to. I have a folder for my service account keys:

```
ProjectDirectory/environments/service_account_keys
```

If you open the key file you'll see:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "my-project",
  "private_key_id": "12345abcde",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n1673randomcharacters...=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "google-cloud-service@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "12345",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/google-cloud-service%40my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

Don't try to get the service account key JSON for an existing key. This is impossible, as far as I can see. If you need to download a service account key, make a new key. They're free.

### Hook Up Your Cloud Function to your Service Account Key

This is the crazy, undocumented part. The Google Cloud Support people don't even know about this.

To connect your Cloud Function to your service account key to run in the **Firebase Emulators**, make a `TranslationServiceClient(options)` object:

```
const options = {
  keyFilename: '/Users/TDK/VisualStudioCodeProjects/MyProjectDirectory/environments/service_account_keys/my-project-12345.json',
};
import { TranslationServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/translate';
const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient(options);
```

You're passing the path to your service account key as the parameter of `TranslationServiceClient(options)`. Your `options` object has a single property, `keyFilename`. The value of the property is the path to your service account key. I prefer absolute paths but you can use a relative path if you prefer.

Here's the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/translate/latest/v3beta1.TranslationServiceClient.html) for the `TranslationServiceClient`  type. You can see that there are many more properties. It looks like you could use the `credentials` property to put the service account email and its private key into your Cloud Function. This would be a bad idea as you might inadvertently upload your Cloud Function to an insecure repository and expose your private key to the public.

To connect your Cloud Function to your service account key to run in the **Firebase Cloud**, make a `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` constant:

```
import { TranslationServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/translate';
const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient();
export const GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = '/Users/TDK/VisualStudioCodeProjects/MyProjectDirectory/environments/service_account_keys/my-project-12345.json';
```

Don't ask how long it took me to figure out that the Firebase emulator and cloud need different code.

### Deploy Your Cloud Function with a Service Account

Normally we deploy our Firebase Cloud Functions like this:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:myAwesomeFunction
```

There's another way to deploy Cloud Functions, which allows you to hook up a service account:

```
gcloud functions deploy myAwesomeFunction --service-account my-awesome-function@my-awesome-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

If you deploy your Cloud Function with `gcloud` and the service account you don't need to hook up the credentials key file in your code. This is easy and appears to be higher security.

However...The last time I tried to do this I got an error saying that it couldn't find the `lib/index.js` file. This is the file specified in the `main` property in `functions/package.json`. When you run `npm run build` before you deploy a Cloud Function, TypeScript transpiles your code into JavaScript, from `src/index.ts` to `lib/index.js`. `gcloud` used to be able to find the JavaScript file but now it can't.

And the Firebase team has never implemented this. You can't do:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:myAwesomeFunction --service-account my-awesome-function@my-awesome-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Apparently this isn't recommended for Firebase Cloud Functions.

And I don't see this the documentation referenced in this answer. So maybe this isn't the best way to secure service account access.

### Test Your Function

Call your function and look at your logs and you should see your Firebase Cloud Function execute.

Remember to transpile your TypeScript with `npm run build` before calling your function in the emulator.

### Use a Service Account to Fix a CORS Error

Sometimes you get a CORS error when you call a Cloud Function. You can use a service account to fix a CORS error. Select your project service account (`my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`), make a new key, and save it to your `environments`. Take the `apiKey` property, pass it as the parameter for `defineSecret()`, and then call the Cloud Function with the `apiKey`:

```js
import { defineSecret } from "firebase-functions/params";
const apiKey = defineSecret("12345");
export const CallUppercase = onCall({ secrets: [apiKey] }, (request) => {
  ...
});
```

Often these aren't CORS errors but instead are something else, such as you didn't deploy the Cloud Function to the cloud, or you didn't transpile the Cloud Function before calling it in the emulator.

### Workload Identity Federation

When you made your service account key you saw a box that said

> Service account keys could pose a security risk if compromised. We
> recommend that you avoid downloading service account keys and instead
> use the [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity?hl=en). You can learn more about
> the best way to authenticate service accounts on Google Cloud
> [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity?hl=en).

The latter link goes to the blog post [Choose the best way to use and authenticate service accounts on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/how-to-authenticate-service-accounts-to-help-keep-applications-secure). This blog post discusses four use cases:

1. Attaching service accounts to Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, and other applications deployed on Google Cloud
2. Attaching service accounts to Kubernetes pods
3. Attaching service accounts to applications not running on Google Cloud
4. Downloading service account keys

We just did the latter, which is recommended only when the former options are unavailable. The first option seems to be what Google recommends. The [Workload identity federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) documentation talks about Amazon AWS, Microsoft Azure, and other cloud computing platforms but doesn't talk about Google Cloud Functions. The [Securing Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing?hl=en) documents are about authorizing who gets to call your Cloud Functions, not about authorizing your Cloud Functions to call other Google Cloud Services. I can't find documentation for a better way to connect Cloud Functions for Cloud Services than the downloaded service account keys.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to replicate your sample code. Just as @DazWilkin mentioned, you need to bind your service account to the role which includes `cloudtranslate.generalModels.predict`.

1. Go to [GCP IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/)
2. Click on `GRANT ACCESS`
3. Under `New principals` enter your service account.
4. Click on `Select a role` and select either Cloud Translation API Admin (`roles/cloudtranslate.admin`) or Cloud Translation API Editor (`roles/cloudtranslate.editor`) or Cloud Translation API User (`roles/cloudtranslate.user`) based on the `cloudtranslate.generalModels.predict` permission on the [IAM permissions reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) link
5. Redeploy your project