# Connect Firebase Cloud Function to Google Cloud Translate via an IAM service account and an OAuth 2 access token?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to upgrade my Cloud Functions for Firebase from 1st gen to 2nd gen. I'm stuck trying to hook up a Cloud Function to Google Cloud Translate via an IAM service account.

Eight months I asked and answered the question [Authorize access to Google Cloud Translate from Firebase Cloud Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821144/authorize-access-to-google-cloud-translate-from-firebase-cloud-function) The code that solved the problem now throws a TypeScript error.

```js
const { TranslationServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/translate');
const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient('google-cloud-translate@my-awesome-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com');
```

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClientOptions'.ts(2345)
```

I'm confused as to what type TypeScript wants to see in that parameter. I can't find a type 'ClientOptions' for Google Translate. I found a type [TranslationServiceClient](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/translate/latest/v3.TranslationServiceClient.html) and wrote this code:

```js
const options = {
  credentials: {
    client_email: 'google-cloud-translate@my-awesome-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    private_key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n1234567890=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  },
  // email: 'google-cloud-translate@my-awesome-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
  keyFilename: '../../environments/service_account_keys/my-awesome-app-12345.json',
  // port: ,
  projectId: 'my-awesome-app',
  // apiEndpoint:  ,
  // clientConfig: ,
  // fallback: ,
};
import { TranslationServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/translate';
const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient(options);
```

TypeScript compiles this code. When I call the function I get this error in the logs:

```
Exception from a finished function: Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

That URL says that the page is deprecated and sends me to a page about logging in users with Sign In for Google, not info about hooking up Google Cloud Service with IAM service accounts in Google Cloud Functions.

I know how to get a OAuth 2 access token from my Google Console Shell. I don't see a property in the type TranslationServiceClient to put an OAuth 2 access token. Where do I put the OAuth 2 access token?

Comment: I don't code in JS often, but I think you do not need both `credentials` and `keyFilename`. Try just using `keyFilename` with the correct path to the service account JSON key file. Specify `projectId` as well.