# Is there a way to deploy Firebase cloud functions with a Google IAM service account?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I used to be able to deploy Cloud Functions for Firebase with a service account with this:

```
gcloud functions deploy MyFunction --service-account my-function@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

That now throws an error that it can't find `lib/index.js`. I've tried different paths in `main:` in `package.json` but nothing works. Any suggestions for fixing that error?

And is there a way to deploy Firebase Cloud Functions with an IAM service account? This doesn't work:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:MyFunction --service-account myfunction@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The emulator requires a path to the service account key this way:

```js
const options = {
  keyFilename: ".../.../environments/service_account_keys/my-project-12345.json",
};
import { TranslationServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/translate';
const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient(options);
```

The cloud requires a path to the service account key this way:

```js
import { TranslationServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/translate';
const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient();
export const GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = ".../.../environments/service_account_keys/my-project-12345.json";
```

I wrote a long answer explaining how to [Authorize access to Google Cloud Translate from Firebase Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821144/authorize-access-to-google-cloud-translate-from-firebase-cloud-function).

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase CLI does not support this.  You can think of the Firebase CLI as a simplified view of GCP services, and this is not part of the simplified view it exposes.

If you want to see a list of everything the CLI can do, find its [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli). You can also use `--help` on the command line to get help on any command to see what your choices are.